# Ruby and gems reinstalling after update to OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)

Tags: ruby, xcode, rubygems, installation, osx-mavericks

I update my OS_X to 10.9, and have problems with ruby socket I/O library ( cannot connect to port ).
It's very strange problem, cause all configuration params is setup correctly. 
So I think it may be OS_X 10.9 (or updated Xcode) compatibility problems.

I install Command Line tools for just updated Xcode. ( it's imposible to install ruby without it ).

I have successfully reinstall ruby 1.9.3. But when I try to reinstall my gem environment, I see an error:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p448 - #installing.........................................................................................................
Retrieving rubygems-2.0.13
There is no checksum for 'http://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-2.0.13.tgz' or 'rubygems-2.0.13.tgz', it's not possible to validate it.
This could be because your RVM install's list of versions is out of date. You may want to
update your list of rubies by running 'rvm get stable' and try again.
If that does not resolve the issue and you wish to continue with unverified download
add '--verify-downloads 1' after the command.

There has been an error while trying to fetch rubygems. 
Halting the installation.
```

What I need to do in this situation? 
What does mean 'validation' of my gemsets? 
Why my gems are out of the date?

Please, help me to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run in my terminal 'rvm get stable' to get stable rvm. Successful compleate, cool.
And try to reinstall ruby 1.9.3 without errors second time

Here I have a warning:

`Warning: found user selected compiler '/usr/local/opt/apple-gcc42/bin/gcc-4.2',
    this will suppress RVM auto detection mechanisms.`

Now it install for me newest rubygems-2.1.10 (not 2.0.13).

New errors ^_^:

```
Error running '__rvm_with ruby-1.9.3-p448 /Users/bmalets/.rvm/scripts/gemsets pristine',
please read /Users/bmalets/.rvm/log/1383094697_ruby-1.9.3-p448/gemset.pristine-ruby-1.9.3-p448.log
```

I navigate ot my rails3/ruby1.9.3 project and run it. At first look it works fine.

So, It looks like successfully updated))))))

P.S I believe that update to new versions of OS_X will not be so horrible as update to iOS 7. New GUI in Calendar and Notes apps is like a shit. I'm so disappointed in apple now :'(.